# jQuery pagination with first last, prev and next buttons

Tags: jquery, pagination

Hi I have the following code for jquery pagination (with first, last, previus, next) and try as I might I can't get it to work any ideas how to make it work ?

[This is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/w9nxcwoy/4/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  switch_page(n);
});  

function switch_page(n){
        var which_page = 0;
    which_page = Math.abs((which_page + n) % 4);
    $("div").not("eq("+which_page+")").each(function(){ $(this).hide(); });
    $("div:eq("+which_page+")").show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#next").click(function(){ switch_page( 1); });
    $("#prev").click(function(){ switch_page(-1); });
    $("#pag1").click(function(){ which_page = 0; switch_page(0); });
    $("#pag2").click(function(){ which_page = 1; switch_page(0); });
    $("#pag3").click(function(){ which_page = 2; switch_page(0); });
    $("#pag4").click(function(){ which_page = 3; switch_page(0); });
    $("#frst").click(function(){ which_page = 0; switch_page(0); });
    $("#last").click(function(){ which_page = 3; switch_page(0); });
});
```

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to state what is happening with your code and what you expect to happen. Asking for help to "make it work" is too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

1. When you initially call `switch_page(n)`, there's no `n` defined. Your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should have reported that.  Move it's declaration somewhere it can be seen by all the functions.
2. Since we have to start *somewhere*, call `switch_page(0)` to start.
3. `"eq(...)"` should be `":eq(...)"`
4. No need to call `.each()` to hide elements individually; `.hide()` will happily hide the whole set at once.

```js
var which_page = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  switch_page(0);
});

function switch_page(n) {
  which_page = Math.abs((which_page + n) % 4);
  $("div").not(":eq(" + which_page + ")").hide();
  $("div:eq(" + which_page + ")").show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next").click(function() {
    switch_page(1);
  });
  $("#prev").click(function() {
    switch_page(-1);
  });
  $("#pag1").click(function() {
    which_page = 0;
    switch_page(0);
  });
  $("#pag2").click(function() {
    which_page = 1;
    switch_page(0);
  });
  $("#pag3").click(function() {
    which_page = 2;
    switch_page(0);
  });
  $("#pag4").click(function() {
    which_page = 3;
    switch_page(0);
  });
  $("#frst").click(function() {
    which_page = 0;
    switch_page(0);
  });
  $("#last").click(function() {
    which_page = 3;
    switch_page(0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>page 1</div>
<div>page 2</div>
<div>page 3</div>
<div>page 4</div>

<button id=frst>(first)</button>
<button id=prev>(prev)</button>

<button id=pag1>(1)</button>
<button id=pag2>(2)</button>
<button id=pag3>(3)</button>
<button id=pag4>(4)</button>
<button id=next>(next)</button>


<button id=last>(last)</button>
```